# IDE/compiler PC benchmark to compare my PCs performance?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2008, upgrade, benchmarking

I'm looking for a benchmark (and results on other PCs) which would give me an idea of the development performance gain I could get by upgrading my PC, also the benchmark could be used to justify the upgrade to my boss.

I use Visual Studio 2008 for my development, so I'd like to get an idea of by what factor the build times would be improved, and also it would be good if the benchmark could incorporate IDE performance (i.e. when editing, using intellisense, opening code files etc) into its result.

I currently have an AMD 3800x2, with 2GB RAM on Vista 32.  For example, I'd like to know what kind of performance gain I'd see in Visual Studio 2008 with a Q6600, 4GB RAM on Vista 64.  And also with other processors, and other RAM sizes... also see whether hard disk performance is a big factor.

EDIT: I mentioned Vista 64 because I'm aware that Vista 32 can only use 3GB RAM maximum.  So I'd presume that wanting to use more RAM would require Vista 64, but perhaps it could still be slower overall there is a large overhead in using the 32 bit VS 2008 on 64 bit OS.

Comment: If your boss requires this type of justification, find a new boss :)

Comment: I don't agree that this question should be closed.  Rick is trying to build a good development machine, which is programming related.

Comment: Yes, I agree, and seem to have the option to re-open the question, so have done that.

Comment: A question about programmer tools is certainly programming related.

Comment: It's not a large overhead - it still runs really well. But you are right about the RAM limit. As VS is 32-bit the app wouldn't be able to use that extra RAM anyway...

Comment: 32 bit machines can use more than 4 Gb RAM using an extra layer of indirection (named PE?) I do not know if Windows can provide more than 4 Gb memory to a single process but if you have 8 Gb disk cache your build time should shorten quite a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anandtech have started using a build of Chromium in Visual Studio 2008 as a CPU benchmark.

http://www.anandtech.com/show/4083/the-sandy-bridge-review-intel-core-i5-2600k-i5-2500k-and-core-i3-2100-tested/19

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't know of any benchmarks for the IDE specifically.

However, Vista-64 won't run VS any faster than Vista-32 because VS is 32-bit. If anything it will run slightly slower on Vista-64. To run any 32-bit application on Vista x64, the OS uses a translation layer called WOW64:

[WOW64 is a compatibility environment provided by the operating system that allows a 32-bit application to run on a Windows 64-bit operating system.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOW64)

A concern would be that having to run Visual Studio under WOW64, it may actually run slower on Vista x64 than Visa x86. Obviously under x86 it won’t need to go through a translation process.

There are a lot of comparisons between running 32-bit applications on 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows on the web. And in general if any benefits are seen at all, they are relatively minor. One such test does show an improvement in only certain limited circumstances, and even reduced performance for some 32-bit apps running in a 64-bit environment:

[What we saw was that using 64-bit memory addressing, or especially converting the memory addressing of a 32-bit executable to work with the 64-bit version of XP, imposed a slight memory bandwidth hit. While not big enough to be an issue, it proves what we were already seeing from the previous benchmark results: 32-bit code runs slightly slower in a 64-bit environment than it does in its native 32-bit habitat.](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleid=1665&amp;page=7)

Better RAM and disk performance will certainly help. VS does a lot of disk IO when you're building.

Scott has a good post about this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/01/tip-trick-hard-drive-speed-and-visual-studio-performance.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I read through the links and they were quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this [blog post](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/12/04/solid-state-drive-enhance-developers-productivity.aspx) from Patrick Smacchia. It's clear enough to me that the difference is in the HDD/SSD so go for a SSD.

Comment: It does seem likely that the performance gain is due to the SSD, although there are quite a lot of differences between the two machines.  Shame that SSD are still quite expensive, and there is the question about their longer term reliability.

Comment: The problem with an SSD is that VS is I/O intensive - the drive wouldn't last long enough to be economical. If you use a fast SD card that will be cheap enough and fast enough to make sense. That's what I use with my SSD...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any benchmarks that compare Visual Studio.... but I can tell you this; the biggest bang for your buck would be buying a faster harddrive (like the 300GB Velociraptor) and making sure you have sufficient RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I just can say, that an overview of clients within an environment of "incredibuild"-enhanced network could give you such a speed-comparison.
we use this with 10 clients (all equal in hardware, though :( )

maybe here are some developers of bigger companies than i work at to give you interesting information?!

Answer (score 0):

There are many tasks, but as far as I have researched:

- VS start - SSD & RAM
- Compile project - fast CPU with many cores (compilation utilize more cores/HT) + SSD
- Find in files/find reference - max RAM with highest possible speed + SSD

So generally it's good to have everything great. At least 4 cores with at least 8-16 GB RAM with decent SSD.